# CreateView form_invalid for multiple forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am working with a CBV that uses 2 `ModelForm` instances. I would like to display the individual form errors. It seems like this is a little challenging when using multiple forms in a class based view.

Heres a smaller snippet to show what I am working with...

```
class EmployeeCreate(CreateView):


    form_class = EmployeeCreateForm
    form_class_2 = AddressCreateForm


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        address_form = self.form_class_2(request.POST)
    
        # Make sure both forms are validated
        if employee_form.is_valid() and address_form.is_valid():
            employee = employee_form.save(commit=False)
            address = address_form.save(commit=False)
            employee.parent = self.request.user
            employee.save()
            address.user = employee
            address.save()
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Employee created successfully.'}, status=200)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(**kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # render both forms to create an Account, and Address
        context = super(EmployeeCreateView, self).get_context_data()
        context['employee_form'] = self.form_class
        context['address_form'] =  self.form_class_2
        return context

    def form_invalid(self, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

Now when the form is invalid, the `form_invalid` method is getting called and returning the JsonResponse message, but I would much rather return the specific form error.

I am trying to find a way to display each individual form error for the `employee_form` and the `address_form`. Is there a possible way to do this override in the `form_invalid` method?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you are returning both forms error in single JsonResponse. Instead you should return different forms error in single JsonResponse like

```
return JsonResponse({'employee_form_errors': self.form_invalid(employee_form),
'address_form_errors': self.form_invalid(address_form) }, status=400)
```

you should use individually use `form_invalid` with both forms.